# Why are "server overloaded" error pages apparently immune to server overloads?

Tags: error-handling, server

I'm sure we've all seen those error pages on websites that render when their servers have been overloaded. They're custom-built, so I assume they must be part of the website's source code.

So how can these pages be rendered when the server is down, when other pages can't be? Can static pages can be viewed by an unlimited number of people?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "rendered" is what you mean - rendering happens inside the client's browser, not on the server.  "Served" perhaps is the word you are looking for.

Obviously the number of static pages that can be served in any fixed amount of time is not unlimited - all resources are finite - but serving a static page usually takes much less resources (cpu time, memory, etc) than generating a dynamic page, which may require substantial computation, database access, etc.  A static page that only needs to communicate an error message can also be very small - perhaps just a few bytes - so it may also need much less bandwidth than the "normal" dynamic page that would be served.  So any given server will likely be able to serve static error pages at a much greater rate than dynamic pages containing the site's usual content.